# Nuxtjs/Vuejs CSS styles are conflicting for 2 components

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have 2 different components in my Vuejs/Nuxtjs application: `pages/Create.vue` and `pages/Design.vue`. I have the stylesheet `assets/css/styles.css`.

Within the stylesheet `styles.css` I have a style: `overflow:hidden;`. This style sheet has been added only to my `Design.vue` component and not to my `Create.vue` component. However, I see that this style is impacting my `Create.vue` without even including it.

If I modify to `overflow:auto;` then everything works perfectly in `Create.vue` but `Design.vue` gets messed up.

I tried following things but still had no luck in making both components work perfectly:

1. Tried adding `<style scoped>` to both my `Create.vue & Design.vue` then also styles in `Design.vue` is getting messed up.
2. Tried adding `overflow:hidden;` to my `Create.vue` but that's not working either.
3. Tried adding `scoped` to both components then also its not working perfectly for me.

Following is the code I have from both components:
`styles.css`

```
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

`Create.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <!-- My code with overflowing the page-->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

/* OTHER STYLES */
</style>
```

`Design.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div>
      <!-- My code with overflowing the page-->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>
@import "~/assets/css/styles.css";

/* OTHER STYLES */
</style>
```

Comment: Not sure why you are trying several things at the same time and counting on luck here. The idea overall: start by having `style scoped` for all of your `.vue` components, otherwise the style will flow out of the component and be applied globally, something that you probably don't want (especially because of CSS conflicts). Then, if you want to add some global style to your whole Nuxt app, add it globally `css` key in `nuxt.config.js`. Then, if you want to add some style to a specific component, import it there (if you want to clean the `style` section of your component, mainly).

Comment: Not sure how you started but `overflow: hidden` is probably nice globally, looking at the `html + body` selectors. Then, if something is messed-up, it's probably that you started wrong initially, still okay to fix it now and use proper scoping of your styles. If your code is getting out of control somehow, it's probably because of the internal CSS/HTML of each component. You could maybe add a `hidden: overflow` to both of your components but the better idea would probably to design a responsive layout at first.

Comment: @kissu Thanks a lot for the response. Actually, I am following a similar approach. I have a `styles.css` which is needed only for my `Design.vue` so added it as `@import` and that has been marked as `scoped`, I am seeing that the styles from `@import` is not added at all when I have `scoped` so I removed the scoped and everything now works perfectly but now, my `Create.vue` gets messed up as its leaked to that component as well.